# Can't select option from Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the Bootstrap UI to allow the user to choose an option from this dropdown:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="areaCode">+1</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <select id="areaCodes" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <option value="1">US: +1</option>
        <option value="44">UK: +44</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#1, #44").click(function (e) {
    $("#label").html("+" + $(this).attr("id") + " <span class='caret'></span>");
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
    if ($(this).attr("id") == '1') {
        phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUK');
        phone.rules('add', {
            phoneUS: true
        });
    } else {
        phone.rules('remove', 'phoneUS');
        phone.rules('add', {
            phoneUK: true
        });
    }
});

$('.phone').on('input', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

It just automatically selects "+1" and closes.

Link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/rt8892rx/)

Comment: You seem to be using Bootstrap in an odd manner. Why do you have a `<select>` within a dropdown? Does that seem a little redundant to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a select list and options you need to use ul and li.

Example from bootstrap docs

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="isSelected"  role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rt8892rx/3/

This will use the ul and li and it has the added code to get the click event and change the text of the button for select list like functionality.

```
$("#somelist li").click(function(){

    //sets button text
    $("#label").text($($(this).find("a")).text())

    //removes isSelected class
    $("#somelist li a").removeClass("isSelected");

    //add isSlected Class to clicked element
    $($(this).find('a')).addClass("isSelected")
    alert("working")
})
```

Comment: The problem with switching to using
`<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="areaCodes" role="menu">
                              <li><a href="#" id="1">US: +1</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#" id="44">UK: +44</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>` is that I can't grab the selected area code with `$("#areaCodes").find(":selected").val()`

Comment: @Matt No, but you can assign a `.click()` function to each of the `<li>`'s that returns `$(this).text()` can you not? There's always another method to accomplish what you need :)

Comment: Instead of the selected one just list for the one that gets clicked. You could replace the buttons text with the clicked one to get a similar functionality of the selectlist as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd apply that to the existing `.click()` function I have already. Can you modify the fiddle to give a hint?

Comment: @Matt I updated your jsfiddle example with what i was talking about.

Comment: Thanks @mattfetz. The issue is that this doesn't work with `$("#areaCodes").find(":selected").val()` to append to the query string I had with the previous implementation:

`url: '/textMessage/' + $("#areaCodes").find(":selected").val() + $('input[name="phone"]').val()`

Comment: Oh ok well that can be fixed. Have a hidden input some where and when you click the desired item it will set the hidden input to the new value. Then when you need to just reference the hidden value. Or maybe even easier you could add a isSelected class to the clicked list item when clicked. Just remember to remove the isselected class from the current so you don't have multiple elements with that class. Then find the element with that class and get its value.

Comment: @Matt I updated the answer with the adding of a class and referencing. The jsfiddle example is updated as well if you want to test it. Just select a new value and press the test it button on the bottom to get the new selected item. You can use that for what you need

Comment: In doing so, how do I append the clicked value to the query string, so I can append it to the number input by the user?

`url: '/textMessage/' + $("#areaCodes a:selected").val($(this)) + $('input[name="phone"]').val()`

The value being submitted should be either +1 or +44 prepended to the beginning of the users phone number.

Comment: With the code I have in jsfiddle it would look like this: url: '/textMessage/' + $("#somelist .isSelected").text() + $('input[name="phone"]').val()

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '#areaCodes', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```